# Registering multiple Jackson Converters

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I'm trying to configure a Jackson objectMapper to handle conversions from one Map-like DTO to an intermediate domain POJO, and from there to another Map-like DTO.

If I manually instantiate all the `StdConverter<FromMap, POJO>` and `StdConverter<POJO, ToMap>` it works as expected.

How can I configure the ObjectMapper with my custom converters?

Answer (score 5):

Seems that converters can be registered using the `StdDelegatingSerializer` as follows:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule()
    .addSerializer(String.class, new StdDelegatingSerializer(
        new Converters.StringToAttributeValue()))
```